# Insert record in two database store simultaneously

Tags: indexeddb

I have two database in indexed db and stores inside them.

```
DB1 : School --> Store : School_store
DB2 : Hospital  --> Store : Hospital_store
```

I have some common records to be inserted in both database simultaneously.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just call the insert method on both db's. it's not possible to do this in a single transaction. If you want to atchieve this, use a single db instead

Comment: I am calling insert method on both db's, giving error - version change transaction is already in use.

Comment: Can you provide a simple coude sample? If I see this error I think you are trying to open the same db twice in version change mode.